# Pylance 'Expression cannot be assigned to declared type' when instantiating class that has generic tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing, pylance

The following python code, which is a simplified version of my actual use-case:

```
from typing import Generic, Tuple, TypeVar

Type = TypeVar("Type", contravariant=True)

class Interface(Generic[Type]):
    pass

SpecType = TypeVar("SpecType")

class Implementation(Interface[Tuple[str, SpecType]], Generic[SpecType]):
    pass

a: Interface[Tuple[str, float]] = Implementation[float]()
```

Produces the following Pylance error (using the Pylance VSCode extension):

```
Expression of type "Implementation[float]" cannot be assigned to declared type "Interface[Tuple[str, float]]"
  "Implementation[float]" is incompatible with "Interface[Tuple[str, float]]"
    TypeVar "Type@Interface" is contravariant
      "Tuple[str, SpecType@Implementation]" is incompatible with "Tuple[str, float]"
        Tuple entry 2 is incorrect type
          "object*" is incompatible with "float"
```

This error is produced by the last line:

```
a: Interface[Tuple[str, float]] = Implementation[float]()
```

This error does not really make sense. The error message seems to think the real-type assigned to the generic type `SpecType@Implementation` is `object*`, when clearly `float` is passed explicitly as the value of the `SpecType` `TypeVar` when `Implementation` is instantiated.

I think there should be no error on this assignment, since `Implementation[float]` is an `Interface[Tuple[str, float]]` by the definition of the class `Implementation`.

Interestingly, this error is only produced when the `Type` `TypeVar` is contravariant, no error when covariant or invariant. Changing the variance of `SpecType` has no effect. I do not understand why the variance would matter here, since the generic parameter is 'Tuple[str, float]' on both sides of the assignment.

I am using python 3.11.0, but the same issue also occurs in python 3.6.8.

Comment: I agree this seems like a false positive on the part of Pylance. `mypy` for example does not object to that code (see [playground](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=441d57147187b3ba16ace5cb5397ccfe)). As a side note, I am pretty sure you don't need the additional `Generic` base for `Implementation`. But that has nothing to do with the error.